# springboot + hibernate + javaFX

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm stuck in this for a few days without getting anywhere. 
Here's the deal..Im building an app that uses springboot (mainly o use crudeRepository) with javafx and hibernate.

but i keeping getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.jus.trt9.PjeMonitor.view.MonitorPjeController.mouseEvent(MonitorPjeController.java:153)
    ... 62 more
```

This happens because the crudrepository clientRepo is null, don't know why...in normal execution it should have somethinh like this:

org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@5a0a3243

anybody, know why ? thank you in advance.

ClientRepo.java
    imports ...

```
/*TODO essa classe deve implementar o CrudRepository
que vem do spring-DATA-core
*/
@Repository
public interface ClientRepo extends CrudRepository<Client, Integer> {

}
```

MainApp.java

```
package br.jus.trt9.PjeMonitor;

imports
... 

/*
 * @AutoConfigurationPackage
 * 
 * @ComponentScan(basePackages = "br.jus.trt9.PjeMonitor")
 * 
 * @EnableAutoConfiguration
 */

//FIXME esse warning na inicialização
/* Unable to proxy method [public final void br.jus.trt9.PjeMonitor.dao.Ge
nericDao.setClazz(java.lang.Class)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.*/
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "br.jus.trt9.PjeMonitor")
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    private ObservableList<Audiencia> audData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private static String[] args;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // applicationContext.ge3tAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

//      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootLayout));
//      primaryStage.show();

         this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
         this.primaryStage.setTitle("Pje Midias Monitor");

        initRootLayout();

        showTableAudiencia();

    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

    public MainApp() {

        audData.add(new Audiencia("12123123213213", LocalDate.now(), "sim"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("22222222222222", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("22222222222222", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("55555555555555", LocalDate.now(), "sim"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("6666666666666", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("7777777777777", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("8888888888888", LocalDate.now(), "sim"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("99999999999999", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("100010110101001", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));

    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */

     public void initRootLayout() {
     try {
     // Load root layout from fxml file.
     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
     loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
     rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

     // problema do classLoader do javaFX
     loader.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

     // Show the scene containing the root layout.
     Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.show();

     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

    public void showTableAudiencia() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/visao.fxml"));
            AnchorPane TableOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            //loader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.  
            rootLayout.setCenter(TableOverview);

            // Give the controller acckess to the main app.
            MonitorPjeController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
            System.out.println("carregou main app");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showCadastroClients() {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/clientcadastro.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Create the dialog Stage.
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Cadastro de máquinas");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public ObservableList<Audiencia> getAudData() {
        return audData;
    }

    public void setAudData(ObservableList<Audiencia> audData) {
        this.audData = audData;
    }

}
```

MonitorPjeController.java

```
package br.jus.trt9.PjeMonitor.view;

import ...;

public class MonitorPjeController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Audiencia> audTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Audiencia, String> audId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Audiencia, LocalDate> dataId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Audiencia, String> assId;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Client> clientcomboBox;

    @FXML
    private Button BtnListaId = new Button();

    @FXML
    private Button BtnListarMaq;

    private ObservableList<Client> myClientComboBoxData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // referencia a aplicacao principal
    private MainApp mainapp;

    //FIXME
    @Autowired
    ClientRepo clientRepo;



        public MonitorPjeController() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        audId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().processoProperty());
        dataId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dataProperty());
        assId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().assinadoProperty());

        Client client = new Client("teste123", "21 vt");

        // sets the combobox options
        myClientComboBoxData.add(client);
        myClientComboBoxData.add(new Client("cta122223", "10 vt"));
        myClientComboBoxData.add(new Client("cta122223", "17 vt"));
        myClientComboBoxData.add(new Client("cta120337", "18 vt"));

        clientcomboBox.setItems(myClientComboBoxData);

        clientcomboBox.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> {
            return new ListCell<Client>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Client item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getVara());
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        clientcomboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Client>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Client maquina) {
                if (maquina == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return maquina.getVara();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Client fromString(String string) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });

    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainapp = mainApp;

        audTable.setItems(mainApp.getAudData());

    }


    // FIXME nao salva
    // TODO em caso de erro enviar msg de erro
    @FXML
    public void mouseEvent() {
        Client client = new Client(1, "cta 12344", "18 vt");
        clientRepo.save(client);

    }

    public ObservableList<Client> getMyClientComboBoxData() {
        return myClientComboBoxData;
    }

    public void setMyClientComboBoxData(ObservableList<Client> myClientComboBoxData) {
        this.myClientComboBoxData = myClientComboBoxData;
    }

}
```

as pointed by @minus, i created an springBoot EntryPoint, but the application starts and exits...i never see the javaFX view.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;


@SpringBootApplication
public class LaunchClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);

    }

}
```

Comment: I fail to see your Spring Boot entry point.

Comment: if i did understand what u want, you mean this?

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }`

Comment: That's standard JavaFX entry point, but I can't see Spring context start.

Comment: as you pointed, the app didint have a spring entry point...so i created one (edited the original post LaunchClass.java). But now, the application runs...and exits. i getting lost here. lol

Comment: FWIW and I have never tried them.  There is a [springboot-javafx-support](http://springboot-javafx-support.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library and a [Spring Boot Java FX integration example](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-labs/tree/master/spring-boot-javafx).  I suggest perhaps you try them.

Comment: Also there is a [Spring Boot Java FX / JPA integration example](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-labs/tree/master/spring-boot-javafx-jpa-demo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it! 
      Following the tip that @jewelsea gave, I studied the framework created by [Felix Roske](http://springboot-javafx-support.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It took a little bit of refactoring of code, mainly in the controller part.

App.java
    imports ...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport {

    /**
     * Note that this is configured in application.properties
     */
    @Value("${app.ui.title:PJe Midia Monitor}")//
    private String windowTitle;



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launchApp(App.class, VisaoView.class, args);
    }

}
```

2- the view class

```
imports ....


@FXMLView(value = "view/visao.fxml")
public class VisaoView extends AbstractFxmlView {

}
```

3- the controller

```
imports ....

@FXMLController
public class MonitorPjeController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Audiencia> audTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Audiencia, String> audId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Audiencia, LocalDate> dataId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Audiencia, String> assId;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Client> clientcomboBox;

    @FXML
    private Button BtnListaId = new Button();

    @FXML
    private Button BtnListarMaq;

    @FXML
    private ObservableList<Client> myClientComboBoxData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private ObservableList<Audiencia> audData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepo clienteRepo;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        populaTabela();

        Client client = new Client("teste123", "21 vt");

        // sets the combobox options
        myClientComboBoxData.add(client);
        myClientComboBoxData.add(new Client("cta122223", "10 vt"));
        myClientComboBoxData.add(new Client("cta122223", "17 vt"));
        myClientComboBoxData.add(new Client("cta120337", "18 vt"));

        clientcomboBox.setItems(myClientComboBoxData);

        clientcomboBox.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> {
            return new ListCell<Client>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Client item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getVara());
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        clientcomboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Client>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Client maquina) {
                if (maquina == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return maquina.getVara();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Client fromString(String string) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });

    }


    public void populaTabela() {
        audData.add(new Audiencia("12123123213213", LocalDate.now(), "sim"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("22222222222222", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("22222222222222", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("55555555555555", LocalDate.now(), "sim"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("6666666666666", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("7777777777777", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("8888888888888", LocalDate.now(), "sim"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("99999999999999", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));
        audData.add(new Audiencia("100010110101001", LocalDate.now(), "nao"));


        audTable.setItems(getAudData());

        audId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().processoProperty());
        dataId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dataProperty());
        assId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().assinadoProperty());
    }

    public ObservableList<Audiencia> getAudData() {
        return audData;
    }

    public void setAudData(ObservableList<Audiencia> audData) {
        this.audData = audData;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not as easy as it seems.

You can start reading [this article](http://steveonjava.com/javafx-and-spring-day-1/) or [this](http://koenserneels.blogspot.it/2012/11/javafx-2-with-spring.html) and from there move on.

The fact is that there are several problems combining javafx and Spring + Hibernate.

The biggest problem is *scope*.

Both Spring and Hibernate have been mostly developed to work within a web applications which has some well defined scopes (Application, Session, Request).

JavaFX have no inherent scopes, you must create custom ones and manage them.

Also there is the not trivial detail that both Spring and JafaFX FXMLLoader should inject fields in the same object (the controller).

Last but not least there is the problem of managing and scoping Hibernate Sessions.

It's a lot of work, and I know it because I did something quite similar with WELD+JavaFX.

Comment: sir, ty for you reply...i will try to see if there is a better way to achieve this, and post some feedback later!

Comment: i solved the problem, i mean...kind of...refactored the entire app. Removed the spring boot, and used javaFX + hibernate alone, its working.  But, sometime, in near future, i'll try the tutorial that jewelsea quoted.
cya

Comment: Good, it's always the sane thing to do to start with the basic and then, when you have some solid ground to build upon, make another step.

Comment: as i said, i did refactored the project, and now the project is running with full springboot,hibernate and javaFX